# Load all of Dynamically Loading HTMLTable - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, html-table

I have code that works to load a HTMLTable, but I recently had a large list and realized it was only pulling the top of the list. Further investigation watching dev console shows multiple "post" requests as I scroll down the table in the browser. I'm debating building code (if I even can) to try and find the last item in the table, and then run the query again, but I wanted to see if I could tackle the root problem "correctly" vs hacking around it.

How can I perhaps simulate scrolling and monitor post requests or any other suggestions?

Here is some sample code, but I can't unfortunatley share the link as its LAN access only. Note: No login in required, but I couldn't figure out how to do it without using an IE Object to generate the cookie that goes along w/ the request (couldn't post via CLI).

```
 Do Until InStr(1, IEObj.document.getElementById("gbox_tbl").innerHTML, "WAREHOUSE") > 0
   DoEvents
 Loop
 Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable, HTMLCollection As IHTMLElementCollection
 Set table = IEObj.document.getElementById("gbox_tbl")
  
 Set ClipBoard = New MSForms.DataObject
 Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
 ClipBoard.SetText table.outerHTML
 ClipBoard.PutInClipboard
 
 Dim TempWS As Worksheet
 Call WorksheetCreateDelIfExists("TempSheet")
 Set TempWS = Worksheets("TempSheet")
 TempWS.Activate
 Range("A1").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 'Stop
 Dim UsedRng As Range
 Set UsedRng = GetUsedRange(TempWS)
 UsedRng.Copy

 Dim FindSMPDestWS As Worksheet, wss As Worksheet, SearchTerm As String, i As Integer
 i = 0
 SearchTerm = "FindWSR"
 For Each wss In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  If Left(wss.Name, Len(SearchTerm)) = SearchTerm Then
   i = i + 1
  End If
 Next wss
 If i = 0 Then
  Call WorksheetCreate("FindWSR")
 Else
  Call WorksheetCreate("FindWSR(" & i & ")")
 End If
 Set FindSMPDestWS = ActiveSheet
 FindSMPDestWS.Activate
 Range("A1").Select
 FindSMPDestWS.Paste
 If Range("A1") <> "Loading..." Then
  Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
  ClipBoard.SetText table.outerHTML
  ClipBoard.PutInClipboard
  Range("A1").Select
  FindSMPDestWS.Paste
 End If
```

Comment: Have you examined the post requests? You need to understand what the POST requests are doing. As we have no sight of those it is very difficult to advise.

Comment: E.g.  the POST request might be for batches of results and in one/more of those results you  might have a total count and a batch size/offset/page number etc, from this data you might be able to formulate the logic to issue your own POST requests to get all the data.

Comment: The two IE typical approaches are to either 1) find an element at the bottom of the page and scroll to it 2) keep scrolling window height and getting element count until doesn't change. This depends on being able to access the scroll element. Examples on SO to search for typically involve `lazy-loading`. Which you use depends on which gives reliable results. A less common method can be to use execScript to monitor for ajax completion if ajax is used for updating. Personally, I would choose POST requests over IE but I understand this may not be possible.

Comment: `couldn't post via CLI` ? Not sure how you are doing this. You might be able to perform all this with CURL.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/183215/handling-lazy-loading-webpages-using-vba , https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/167399/scraper-for-a-lazy-loading-webpage , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba+lazy-load , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50844935/parsing-website-that-doesnt-fully-load-vba/50846524#50846524 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/53546126/6241235

Comment: @QHarr your links got me in the correct direction! I now have a sub that works for both tables, time will tell how "robust" it is. Thanks! PS: What do you think? Criticism welcome always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I ran into another table and my below Sub didn't work correctly so I wanted to tackle this problem again to find a more robust solution. @Qharr tip regarding the term "Lazy Loading" webpage helped along with the URL's in his comment. The below is what I have and it worked on the two tables I tested, but they are both internal pages written by the same company, so YMMV but I'm happy to take suggestions/feedback as always.

Code:

```
Sub Testing()
 'Scroll Entire HTML Table
 Dim ScrollBarDivInt As Integer, StepLng As Long, ScrollElmIDStr As String, LoadingElmIDStr As String, LoadingTrueCheckStr As String, LoadingFalseCheckStr As String
 ScrollBarDivInt = 0
 StepLng = 1000
 ScrollElmIDStr = "ui-jqgrid-bdiv"
 LoadingElmIDStr = "load_grdDisposition"
 LoadingTrueCheckStr = "block"
 LoadingFalseCheckStr = "none"
 Call Scroll_HTMLTable(ScrollBarDivInt, StepLng, ScrollElmIDStr, LoadingElmIDStr, LoadingTrueCheckStr, LoadingFalseCheckStr)
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub Scroll_HTMLTable(ByVal ScrollBarDivInt As Integer, ByVal StepLng As Long, ByVal ScrollElmIDStr As String, ByVal LoadingElmIDStr As String, ByVal LoadingTrueCheckStr As String, ByVal LoadingFalseCheckStr As String)
 Dim HLng As Long
 HLng = IEObj.document.getElementsByClassName(ScrollElmIDStr)(ScrollBarDivInt).ScrollHeight
 For i = 1 To HLng Step StepLng
  IEObj.document.getElementsByClassName(ScrollElmIDStr)(ScrollBarDivInt).ScrollTop = i
  Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:1"))
  If InStr(IEObj.document.getElementById(LoadingElmIDStr).outerHTML, LoadingTrueCheckStr) > 0 Then UILoading_Bool = True
  If InStr(IEObj.document.getElementById(LoadingElmIDStr).outerHTML, LoadingFalseCheckStr) > 0 Then UILoading_Bool = False
  Debug.Print "UILoading_Bool = " & UILoading_Bool
  Do While UILoading_Bool = True
   Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:1"))
   If InStr(IEObj.document.getElementById(LoadingElmIDStr).outerHTML, LoadingTrueCheckStr) > 0 Then UILoading_Bool = True
   If InStr(IEObj.document.getElementById(LoadingElmIDStr).outerHTML, LoadingFalseCheckStr) > 0 Then UILoading_Bool = False
  Loop
 Next
End Sub
```

Note: I was able to scroll directly to the bottom with the below, but my Webpage was really Lazy, it didn't load the "middle" of the table unless I paused as I scrolled, hence the "wait".

```
IEObj.document.getElementsByClassName(ScrollElmIDStr)(ScrollBarDivInt).ScrollTop = IEObj.document.getElementsByClassName(ScrollElmIDStr)(ScrollBarDivInt).ScrollHeight
```

End Update

---

This is not exactly clean, but it does work for now, unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to "check" that the page has loaded before re-setting the table to check the length. I'm using "application.wait" which worked fine in my testing, but I'll try to improve the loop later. I'm also up for suggestions still on better ways to tackle this.

```
Public Sub ScrollTable(table As MSHTML.HTMLTable)
 Dim tcell As Object, tcells As Object, ltablerow As Long, c As Long
  Set tcells = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")
  Do
  c = 0
  ltablerow = tcells.Length
  'Stop
  For Each tcell In tcells
  c = c + 1
   If c > ltablerow - 5 Then
    tcell.Click
    tcell.Focus
    SendKeys "{DOWN}"
    SendKeys "{DOWN}"
   End If
  Next
  Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
  Set tcells = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")
  Loop Until tcells.Length = ltablerow

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I would consider getting the awesome free [rubberduck add-in](https://rubberduckvba.com/) and using its code inspection and code formatting features. The above would benefit from some logical whitespace (particular for older eyes like mine) and 4 point indents (IMO). Some low hanging fruit include 1) I can see implicit ByRef where ByVal can be used, use of deprecated CALL keyword,  generic typing when you could use specific typing and prefix with the appropriate class, need for a prevention of infinite loop exit strategy

Comment: Unnecessary comparisons e.g. `Do While UILoading_Bool = True` can be `Do While UILoading_Bool`.  You know about `SendKeys` issues already and object focus. `INT` where `Long` might as well be the default to use. Whether you wish to follow the VBA case rules for variables/subs etc.... Those are some initial low fruit items that pertain less to that actual approach being used. Much harder to comment on that as I can't repro your situ. I have outlined the common solutions to your generic situation of lazy-loading.

Comment: The IF lines in `Scroll_HTMLTable`  likely can be re-factored into a single line but that would involve thinking through the test a bit more overall as that test if very much about knowing when loading done.